# Angular 7 - how to use p-dialog of prime-ng in easy way

Tags: angular, angular7

I am using a prime-ng component p-dialog. I created a MyModal component for modal.i want to open this MyModal component on click event like uib-modal. Is any easy way to do like uib-modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your MyModal component tag to the embedding component template and toggle it using `*ngIf`.

```
<my-modal *ngIf="show" name="{{ name }}"></my-modal>

<button (click)="show = true">show dialog</button>
```

Here's a working StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m9bphb